# Error in mapping the return data from my backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to map the below JSON data which I get it from my backend using fetch API in JavaScript but for some reason I am not able to map it. How can I map this JSON data?

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "_id": "628dfeedc21a4f36907c6600",
      "title": "Hellow world",
      "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
      "createdAt": "2022-05-25T10:03:25.502Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-25T10:03:25.502Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "629095332818f95349543ed9",
      "title": "Buggy world",
      "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book",
      "createdAt": "2022-05-27T09:09:07.462Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-05-27T09:09:07.462Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Every time I map I got error saying:

```
Home.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function
```

maybe because the data is not an array data. How to successfully handle this file?

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { getPost } from "../helper/getPost";

const Home = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);


  const loadPosts = () => {
    getPost().then((data) => {
      setPosts(data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container fluid="xl" className="bg-light border mt-5 mb-5">
      {posts.map((post, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="mb-5">{post.title}</h1>
            <p className="mb-5">{post.content}</p>
            <p>posted by Mang, 24-12-2002</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

getPost.js

```
import { API } from "../backend";

export const getPost = () => {
  return fetch(`${API}/posts`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
        return response.json();
      } else {
        console.log("NOT SUCCESS!");
        return response.status(400).json({
          error: "Data not available",
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: try `setPosts(data?.posts ?? []);`

Comment: try  setPosts(data.posts);

Comment: hey @Chiller setPosts(data.posts); works  bro thank you so much :)